# Tablename with ID "Some_ID" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted? Django Sqlite

Tags: django

I have database with many tables; three of those which are interlinked via primary and foreign keys are "Vendor_Details" , "Channel_Details" and "MSO_Details"

**models.py**

```
class Vendor_Details(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Vendor_Details"
    vendor_name = models.CharField(primary_key = True,max_length=50)
    mso_id = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length=20)

class Channel_Details(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Channel_Details"
    channel_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length=20)
    vendor_name = models.ForeignKey(Vendor_Details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channel_logo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    channel_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MSO_Details(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "MSO_Details"
    mso_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor_Details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channel_id = models.ForeignKey(Channel_Details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channel_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

So,
Channel_Details is linked to Vendor_Details with vendor_name and
MSO_Details is linked with Vendor_Details and Channel_Details with mso_id and channel_id respectively.

Now, I am inside Django's Administrator's MSO_Details table and trying to click on edit icon of CHANNEL ID column i get a new window opens with message `Channel_ details with ID "CH6" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?` May be this is because channel_id is primary key of reference table and DB will not allow the changes? But then the message should had been something different. How can i handle this situation? I clicked on edit for CH_006 and message shows CH6. I am confused whats going on here, what is django's DB refering to here? 
Note : I can very well add new CHANNEL_DETAILS after click add button.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had an existing SQLite database that I had been migrating over to Django. All my entities had a UUID column as their primary key.

I had set the primary key column as `django.models.UUIDField` thinking that Django would support it, but it didn't.

So I converted it to a text field with UUID as default value, it started working again.

```py
class Model(models.Model):
    # id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind  problem for the last two days and the problem was 
1. If on adding details to a new form initially, you do not add the right field required.(I was including both text and integers to a field that was only CharField)

2.The other solution when the error came again was to delete migrations and the database itself and create a new database again(Using the same database name).

Comment: Ohh is it? Then i shall change datatypes for all the ids i defined for type column.  I can also look into second option to delete everything since i have just started and have not

Comment: I will accept this as Valid answer i.e. first solution in sometime. :)

Comment: i have a similar issue where i cannot delete on the detail page of a model but i can delete it on the change list page of the admin, did you find another solution?