# Django Admin cannot find data that exists: 'Perhaps it was deleted?'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a similar problem to this question:

[Tablename with ID "Some_ID" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted? Django Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497987/tablename-with-id-some-id-doesnt-exist-perhaps-it-was-deleted-django-sqlite)

The issue only occurs with one particular model which is:

```
class Kinterms(models.Model):
    kin_category = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    parameter = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    term = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    ipa_term = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    alternative_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    sourceid = models.TextField(db_column='sourceID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.
    coder = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    speaking = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    kinbank_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    glottocode = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    row_id = models.TextField(unique=True, blank=True, primary_key = True)  # This field type is a guess.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'kinterms'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.row_id
```

Which is displayed in the admin file as

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Kinterms, Metadata, Sources, Coder
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Kinterms)
```

As with the linked question, whenever I log into the admin site and click on a row for the Kinterms model I get returned to the admin home page with the banner 'Kinterms with ID "XXXX" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?"

Recreating the DB doesn't fix the issue. I can manually find the values in the DB using the DB viewer.

I have exactly the same set up for all other tables which work fine. The only difference I can note is that this table uses a number for the primary key where as the others are characters. Although they are all TextFields so I assumed this wouldn't matter.

I am not entirely sure what to look for since there are no obvious errors occuring. So please let me know if there is any more information that could be useful.

Comment: Have you tried querying this model using django shell?

Comment: yes I can access row_id using the shell

Comment: I mean can you query the row_id? using this `Kinterms.objects.get(row_id=1)`

Comment: ah - this does not work. do you know why that might be?

Comment: since it is a text field you have specified for row_id, try this `Kinterms.objects.get(row_id="1")` does this work?

Comment: no this doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you get for `Kinterms.objects.order_by('row_id').first().row_id`?

Comment: It returns a 1 - which is incredibly confusing.

Comment: What about 'type(Kinterms.objects.order_by('row_id').first().row_id)`?

Comment: this returns int - which I guess confirms my suspicions

Comment: So if you change your model to `IntegerField` you should be okay.

Comment: Does this mean it was supposed to be (`row_id`) an Integer